# redirect the output of docker-exec

Tags: mysql, docker

`docker exec` is not working for me. If I connect to a running container with `docker exec -it mymachine bash` and run `sh -c 'mysql -u root < /tmp/schema.sql'`, it works.

If I just run `docker exec mymachine sh -c 'mysql -u root < /tmp/schema.sql'`, it doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't do anything. Nor does it give me any errors if I run `docker exec mymachine sh -c 'mysql -u root < /tmp/i_dont_exist.sql'`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
docker exec mymachine "sh -c 'mysql -u root < /tmp/schema.sql'"
```

If not then the '<' operator will be picked up by the shell in the host machine and not the container.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `<` operator is trying to grab from your host rather than your container. Try enclosing the entire command in quotations.